# Multiprocessing forcing idle processors to continue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
Data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def Fn2(obj):
  fname = str(obj) + 'myfile.p'
  pickle.dump(2*obj, open(fname, 'wb'))

p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
p.map(Fn2, Data)
Print "process after the multi-processing" #---Line 1 for question below
```

In the example code above each process is dumping values to a file. So, let's say I have 10 cores and 8 of them have finished and 2 are still busy in function `Fn2`. Is there a way to force the idle processors to continue to `Line 1` above as my rest of code doesn't depend on whether all the values have been dumped into `fname`.

Comment: What is wrong with my question, Mr. Negative vote?

Comment: First, nothing here actually runs `Fn2`. Second, the processes in the process pool only execute jobs sent to the pool; they will not "continue" past the code that submits job requests, because that's not their job.

Comment: Hence it deserves a downvote as you know something and I don't ?

Comment: If you want to use multiple processes to execute the work that comes after `Fn2`, split that work into jobs you can submit to the pool separately and submit them to the pool. Make sure you're not using blocking calls like `map`.

Comment: None of that was a downvote explanation. I downvoted because your code doesn't do what you say it does.

Comment: Yes it was missing a line. I added that line. Thanks. Can you give example of what you mean by not submitting using map.

Comment: `map` waits for all submitted jobs to finish. You can use [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async), `imap`, `imap_unordered`, and similar calls to submit jobs and continue execution without waiting.